# Why the button from event listener 'click' does not trigger event in form despite "type" = "button"?

Tags: javascript

```
const array_of_toys = ['doll','teddy bear','ball']

const first_button = document.createElement('button')

first_button.addEventListener('click', function() {

const form_of_toys = document.createElement('form')

const save_button = document.createElement('input')
save_button.setAttribute('type','submit')

form_of_toys.appendChild(save_button)

array_of_toys.forEach(toy => {

const second_button = document.createElement('button')
second_button.setAttribute('type','button')
second_button.setAttribute('class','second_buttons')
second_button.innerHTML = toy
form_of_toys.appendChild(second_button)



second_button.addEventListener('click', function() {

second_button.innerHTML = 'changed'

})

first_button.replaceWith(form_of_toys)
})})
```

Generally, the first_button works fine, while the second_button doesn't trigger an event at all. As if it was completely inactive. Yes, this form will also have a save button, method, action and everything is in window.onload etc but at the moment I was stuck on the fact that the buttons that are created by forEach loop don't trigger any event at all, I even tried just

```
console.log('messenge')
```

but that doesn't work either. I looked for similar errors on stackoverflow and e.g. tried

```
second_button.addEventListener ('click', event =>
event.preventDefault
console.log('that work')
)
```

but that doesn't work either. ForEach loop is not a problem either, because when I tried to just create one such button without a loop, it doesn't work either. The console also shows no error.

Is there any option for a 'click' event in a form that won't just submit?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your event handlers in the loop, I would delegate it to the document and just look for the class on click.

This will allow you to create as many buttons as you need and use only a single click handler as it is tied to the body on load.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  let btn = e.target;
  if(btn.classList.contains("second_buttons")){
    console.log("do something for second_buttons");
  }
  else if(btn.classList.contains("save_button")){
    console.log("do something for save_button");
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="second_buttons">CLICK1</button>
<button class="save_button">CLICK2</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution would be impractical for my code. Anyway, all other buttons work and (as in the description of the post) it is not about loop at all, because creating a second_button without a loop the problem is still the same. Most likely the problem is related to the fact that this button is a child of the form and the only solution I found on stackoverflow is to change type = "button", but unfortunately it doesn't do anything either. However, I also noticed that by adding second_button.click () this event works fine, but when manually clicking it is inactive.